# HTML5 WebSQL queries

Tags: sql, database, html, cordova, web-sql

Hello I jsut wondering if its posibble to have a query on web sql cause im using a phonegap for phone development and i have an error on this code

```
 tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE log=(\"?\")", [_searchtext], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status2').innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
       document.querySelector('#status2').innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
```

and I can't have any result but on SELECT * FROM DEMO i have a lot of result.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?  What are you expecting as a result using the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

all I am doing is to get all data and put on the loop and condition the data to the searchtext. but i love to make it on the websql. thanks.

Comment: Was this supposed to be an answer or a comment?